# HttpRequest DELETE with body

Tags: httprequest, java-11

I have to submit an http *DELETE* request containing a body. I know how I can do it, but in my case it uses `java.net.http.HttpRequest`. Unfortunately, this component only allows submission of `BodyPublisher` to *PUT* and *POST* requests.

My question is, is there any way to use `HttpRequest` for the problematic *DELETE* request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `HttpRequest.Builder::method` that takes two arguments:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().proxy(HttpClient.Builder.NO_PROXY).build();
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create();
server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress(), 0), 0);
server.createContext("/test/", new HttpHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = exchange.getRequestBody().readAllBytes();
        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, bytes.length == 0 ? -1 : bytes.length);
        try (OutputStream os = exchange.getResponseBody()) {
            os.write(bytes);
        }
    }
});
server.start();
try {
    HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(new URI("http", null,
                    server.getAddress().getHostString(),
                    server.getAddress().getPort(),
                    "/test/test", null, null))
            .method("DELETE", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("hahaha...")).build();
    var resp = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    System.out.println(resp);
    System.out.println(resp.body());
} finally {
    server.stop(0);
}
```